# Randomize Case of PHP string

Tags: php, string

Back in high school my friends and I came up with this cool thing we called "733t speek" where you would randomize the case of words. So for example, "randomize" would become something like "rANDomIZe".

Is there a php function that can do this, along the lines of `strtolower`? I've checked the docs and there is no `strtorandom` function.

Comment: You're basically asking "I need a tool that washes my dishes, walks the dog, and does my homework. I found a hammer, is there something like that but does it all?". No, you get a basic set of tools, and it's up to YOU to use them to accomplish what you want. Expecting PHP to provide a built-in function for every possible thing someone might want to do is simply ludicrous.

Comment: PS, you didn't come up with this.

Comment: `733t speek` was never cool ...

Comment: @cept0 I don't think discussion of what is or was ever cool is not appropriate for this forum. I provided the anecdote for a bit of context and to add personal interest, not to invite personal attacks.

Comment: @MarcB I don't get what's all the downvotes and preaching for? Because he used the word 733T? The guy just comes here and want to know if PHP has a built in function that does some change to a string, not if the function can build his house. What's wrong with being able to ask a valid question here these days? Sheesh...

Comment: @Fuser97381 personal anecdotes are not really appropriate for this forum either. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @Mikey: probably because the question shows no personal effort to solve the problem, and as my first comment said, expecting to be handed a pre-made solution for every problem is ludicrous.

Comment: @Mikey "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. " This was a basic "Google this for me" question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer you're looking for is:

```
Nope.
```

But you can easily make that function yourself, like:

```
$str = "look mawm, i'm so 7eet!";

for ($i=0, $c=strlen($str); $i<$c; $i++)
    $str[$i] = (rand(0, 100) > 50
        ? strtoupper($str[$i])
        : strtolower($str[$i]));

return $str;
```

Comment: That won't do anything to a string that starts in all uppercase.

Comment: @Fuser97381 Good call, updated the code to fix that

Comment: Should be strtoupper and strtolower not $strtoupper and $strtolower

Answer (score 2):

There's no such out of the box function because well... it's pointless. This should work though:

```
$myString = "sample string";
$i=0;
while($i<strlen($myString)){
    $tmp=$myString[$i];
    if(rand() % 2 ==0) $tmp=strtoupper($tmp);
    else $tmp=strtolower($tmp);
    $myString[$i]=$tmp;
    $i++;
}

echo $myString;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a random integer generator, and use a `for` loop to go over each character of the string.

In each loop, If the number generated is even, use the upper case of the character; if odd, use the lower case. Then combine each of the characters together, you should get a `strtorandom` function you wanted.